# facebook graph version of post_authorize_redirect_url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a canvas app and am using the Graph api. There used to be in the REST api a post_authorize_redirect_url for a place to land someone after they first authorize your app (see here for http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/ ). Is there an analagous concept in current canvas app?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not (anymore). You'll need to track yourself if the user has just authorized or is a returning user. Just check your database for the user id, which you are allowed to store. Of course you'll need to store the id at some point of your app.

Answer (score 2):

With the Graph API, you use the redirect_uri parameter.  For example:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=code&redirect_uri={URL}&scope=email&client_id=12345

Details available here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: The redirect_uri variable specifies where the user goes independent of their app authorization status. if set redirect_uri=$URL/first_time.php, it will ALWAYS redirect back to first_time.php even if they have already authorized the app. Facebook docs not so good.